# Grounding insulative material

Tags: electrostatics, insulators

When grounded, can an insulative material keep its charge for any measurable length of time?  Or, I suppose, if it was a perfect insulator, would it discharge at all?

An example might be a charged rubber tire placed on the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a **perfect** insulator, then no charge can flow, and it will never discharge.  Nothing is a 'perfect' insulator, so it's always a question of timescale - determined, primarily, by its resistivity.  This is generally what happens during the build-up of ['static electricity'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity)---for example, from [rubbing together class and fur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect).  Both of those materials are good insulators, and can hold a noticeable charge for an appreciable amount of time.